# Evaluate $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {e^{x+y^2}-1-\sin \left ( x + \frac{y^2}{2} \right )}{x^2+y^2} $

Tags: limits

> $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {e^{x+y^2}-1-\sin \left ( x +
>  \frac{y^2}{2} \right )}{x^2+y^2} $$

I've a few doubts about this limit. I mean, if I take polar coordinates, I get that the limit doesn't exist. And Wolfram agrees with me. Even though, I've found a solution of this problem that doesn't say the same thing; which I transcribe next:

· The Taylor's second order polynomial of $ e^{x+y^2} $ in $ (0,0) $ is $ 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + y^2 $.

· The Taylor's second order polynomial of $ \sin \left ( x + \frac{y^2}{2} \right ) $ in $ (0,0) $ is $ x + \frac{1}{2}y^2 $.

Then:

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {e^{x+y^2}-1-\sin \left ( x + \frac{y^2}{2} \right )}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + y^2-1-(x + \frac{1}{2}y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac {1}{2} $$

Where's the mistake in this?

---

**What I've tried so far:**

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {e^{x+y^2}-1-\sin \left ( x + \frac{y^2}{2} \right )}{x^2+y^2} $$

Let be $ \rho \geq 0 $ and $ \varphi \in [0,2\pi) $, so:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
x = \rho\cos(\varphi)\\ 
y = \rho\sin(\varphi)
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Then:

$$ \begin{align*}
\lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac {e^{\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2}-1-\sin \left ( \rho\cos(\varphi) + \frac{(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2}{2} \right )}{(\rho\cos(\varphi))^2+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2} &= \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac {\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2-\left ( \rho\cos(\varphi) + \frac{(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2}{2} \right )}{(\rho\cos(\varphi))^2+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2} \\ 
 &= \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac {\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2-\left ( \rho\cos(\varphi) + \frac{(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2}{2} \right )}{\rho^2} \\ 
 &= \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac {(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2- \frac{(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2}{2}}{\rho^2} \\ 
 &= \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac {1}{2}\sin^2(\varphi)
\end{align*} $$

Which limit doesn't exit, because the result depends of $ \varphi $ which varies in $ [0,2\pi) $.

And [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28x%2Cy%29-%3E%280%2C0%29%20%28e%5E%28x%2By%5E2%29-1-sin%28x%2By%5E2%2F2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29) you can see that Wolfram agrees.

---

According to a comment below, I've calculated a third order Taylor's polynomial (respecto to $ \rho$) of $ e^{\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2} $. I found that any Taylor's polynomial (in $ \rho = 0 $) of order grater than 2 is exactly $ 1+\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2 $.

Comment: Can you show the work you did in polar coordinates to get that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: I just added it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately you provide no justification whatsoever for the last $=$ sign in the post, which at present remains a complete mystery.

Comment: I already clarified the question.

Comment: ("Already"? No, after my comment--but it is good that you did.) And now the mistake is clear: why stop the expansion of $e^{\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2}$ at $1+\rho\cos(\varphi)+(\rho\sin(\varphi))^2$?

Comment: Yes, I wrote "already" because I was talking in present, I corrected the post by then. First I corrected it, then I commented that. And I don't understand why should I write a third order Taylor's polynomial. I mean, the greatest terms don't cancel each other. And besides, why Wolfram says that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: @francolino, your limit is $1/2$, I think

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where do you think is the mistake taking polar coordinates?

Comment: The mistake (already pointed out by Did) is that you stopped the expansion of $e^{\rho \cos \varphi + (\rho \sin \varphi)^2}$ at $1+ \rho \cos \varphi + (\rho \sin \varphi)^2$. The next term would have been $\tfrac{1}{2}[\rho \cos \varphi + (\rho \sin \varphi)^2]^2$ which when expanded contains a $\tfrac{1}{2}\rho^2\cos^2\varphi$ term. Add this to the $\tfrac{1}{2}\sin^2\varphi$ term to get $\tfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Math question: what @JimmyK4542 said. WA question: dunno, the thing is known to generate countless bugs, to receive a more specific answer you might want to ask the question on a site dedicated to WA.

Answer (score 1):

For $(x,y)$ near $(0,0),$ we have

$$e^{x+y^2} = 1 + (x+y^2) +(x+y^2)^2/2 + O((x+y^2)^3), \sin (x+y^2/2) = (x+y^2/2) +O((x+y^2/2)^3).$$

So the numerator of our expression is

$$(y^2/2 + x^2/2) +  xy^2 + y^4/2 + O((x+y^2)^3) + O((x+y^2/2)^3)= (y^2/2 + x^2/2) + r(x,y).$$

Dividing by $x^2 + y^2$ we get $1/2 + r(x,y)/(x^2+y^2).$ Now $r(x,y)/(x^2+y^2)\to 0.$ I'll leave this to you for now. Thus the desired limit is $1/2.$

Comment: [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](http://mathoverflow.net/a/30355/76570).

Comment: @KeithMcClary Not sure what your comment means.