# How to properly handle multivariate limits.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} & \text{for  $(x,y) \neq (0,0),$}\\
    0 & \text{for  $(x,y) = (0,0).$}
  \end{cases}
$$

I am hoping to show this is continuous, but I do not know how to handle multivariate limits, can I simply take one and then the other or what do you do?

I have no $\varepsilon-\delta$ version of continuity at hand, only the usual limit formulation.

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates? Then show it does not depend on theta as R tends to zero.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Nope, but I will give it a shot. I did not find it looked like an expression that would be easily translated to polar coordinates.

Comment: Well the denominator is r^2 so maybe...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Yea, I know, but that just means that the angle has to cancel from the top where only things are multiplied together...

Comment: if by "...take one and then the other" you mean first take limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ and take limit as $y \rightarrow 0$ then no you can't do that. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407614/lim-y-rightarrow-b-lim-x-rightarrow-a-f-neq-lim-x-y-rightarrow-a/1408783#1408783

Comment: @user280266 Could you give us "the usual limit formulation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|f(x,y)|=\frac{|xy||x^2-y^2|}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{|xy|(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=|xy|$$
which goes to zero as $(x,y)$ goes to zero.